# Polymer - paper-tab: Limited characters inside a tab

Tags: polymer

I've created a way to add dynamic tabs using **paper-tab** component, but I wanted a specific behaviour when adding new tabs.

Right now I'm using **scrollable** and **fit-container**, so when I add a new tabs they will fit in the container, and when necessary activate the scrollable.

```html
<paper-tabs scrollable fit-container>
```

But there are some cases when the string inside a tab is very long, that's not good for mobile devices.

So, what I wanted to do is this:

1. When there's space enough, the long string should appear entirely:
   *One paper-tab with a very long string*

   [image]
2. When adding more tabs, the one with a very long string should truncate to a set number of characters:
   *Multiple tabs*

   [image]
3. And finally, when adding more tabs and the limit of characters inside the long tab is reached, it can not truncate anymore, activating the scrollable option.

I've already tried to work with **max-width** but using this property the tabs don't fit in the container when I have only 1 or 2 tabs.

And I also tried to work with **flex-basis**, but in this case the tabs with a small string will not have a proportional width.

So, if anybody have any ideas for that, that will be great.

Thanks.